# HTML - How to limit the amount of data per webpage, create further pages to display the rest

Tags: html, httpresponse

I'm retrieving data from a database (MongoDB) and displaying them on a webpage using HttpResponse

Ex:

```
while(moredata):
    response = HttpResponse()
    response.write("<p>Data here</p>")
```

However, each query operation returns hundreds of records, that I don't want to display on one single webpage. Is there a way I can limit amount of data displayed per page, and create Next -> links which will enable the user to go to a new page to see the next set of data, and so on?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Its called pagination

Answer (score 0):

Investigate the use of MongoDB's .skip(), .limit(), and .find() methods.